# What is the difference between these 3 Visual Studio Solution Explorer icons?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am seeing 3 different types of icons directly to the right of my .cs filenames in Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.8.1
I'm curious as to what they mean. I checked out:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-view-and-object-browser-icons?view=vs-2017
but couldn't find these icons.

I'm thinking it might be from a plugin or something? not sure. 
There is no common thread linking them as far as GIT, compilation status or errors. I'm brand new to VS and C#, so these things bother me.

[image: c# lock icon]

[image: other c# icons]

thanks!

Comment: If you hover mouse over them you will see the hints

Comment: `there is no common thread linking them as far as GIT` - are you sure about that?

Comment: David and Maccettura have already answered it well enough. I'm just curious what led you to think that it had nothing to do with Git - what did you do to rule that out?

Comment: i was reading it from the command line, and I have 2 similarly named files and i just mistook them. my bad. sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all related to source control, in your case GIT

- The `lock` icon means the file is source controlled and not currently modified or has any pending changes.  If you hover over in VS you will see the status as "Checked In".
- The `plus` icon means its a new file that has yet to be added to source control.  If you hover over in VS you will see the status as "Pending Add".
- The `red check` icon means there is a pending change that is yet to be committed.  If you hover over in VS you will see the status as "Pending Edit".

Comment: It's worth noting that in the case of git version control (as opposed to TFVC), the 'lock' may indicate that it has been committed locally, but will not show that it hasn't been pushed to a remote repository.

Comment: yeah. this was totally my bad. i checked GIT and misread one of the files, which made me think there was no common GIT thread. totally my bad, but thanks for the response. 
I also didn't know i could hover over them to get their meaning... LOL. that seems fairly obvious in retrospect, but i'm BRAND new to VS and everything looks obvious in retrospect. thanks again.

Comment: @PeterAndrus VS is overwhelming, there is a lot going on.

Answer (score 2):

1. The lock means the file is unchanged from the version in source control.
2. The plus means it's a new file not yet tracked in source control.
3. The red tick means the file has been changed and not yet committed to source control.