# How do I get Git to view my project's files in Visual Studio Community 2022?

Tags: c++, git

I'm referring to Git, as used by the GUI in VS Community 2022.

It seems like a simple question, but it doesn't look like anyone else has asked this question.

If you need more details, please ask.  Please don't just ignore this question.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "get `git` to view project files"? git isn't a file viewer...

Comment: Are you asking how to add the project's files into a Git repository from within the VS built-in GUI or what is the question?

Comment: I mean, to get Git to recognize a file as 'unstaged', so that it can be staged.  The 'git changes' viewer says there's no unstaged changes in the working directory, even though I changed and saved a source code file.  So maybe my question could be rephrased as, "How do I place files in the working directory?"
or "how do I tangibly view the working directory?"  
Answer to either might help

Answer (score 0):

> The 'git changes' viewer says there's no unstaged changes in the working directory, even though I changed and saved a source code file

Fall back temporarily to command-line, and check your file is not ignored:

```
cd /path/to/repository
git check-ignore -v -- folder/modified/file
```

Double-check also the icon overlay symbol on those files, as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52430161/6309).

Comment: New problem - cmd prompt on my pc doesn't even recognize git as a file.  I don't know how to get git to run on it.  I installed git

Comment: @nofreewill That is a PATH issue. Check your %PATH% user environment variable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53706956/6309

Comment: Below are my sys paths.  Are there any new ones I should include or delete for whatever reason?

    PATH 1     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

    PATH 2      C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm

   PATH 3      C:\Program Files (x86)\FAHClient

    PATH 4          A:\Apps\SocketeQ\windowsandroid_root\system\bin

    PATH 5       A:\Apps\SocketeQ\windowsandroid_root\system\lib

    PATH 6        C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\atom\bin

     PATH 7     %USERPROFILE%\.dotnet\tools
------
      EDIT: Why comments in stack don't allow new line characters is beyond me.

Comment: @nofreewill check also your User environment variable PATH, as the PATH is the concatenation of both system and user. But make sure you see `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`, assuming you have installed Git for Windows https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases

Comment: I had "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin"  and "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin" but not Git/bin.  Strange

Comment: @nofreewill Exactly: add `Git\bin`, and git should be recognized.

Comment: So I did the git ignore check on the file that I want to stage - and it gives this message.... 
 ---- error: unknown option `consoleapplication1.cpp'

The dir for the file as so named is src, not .git  - should it be in .git?  Should src be in .git?  How do I get .git to interact (I'm guessing this was the repo that init)?

Comment: @nofreewill nothing should be in .git. This just means the command was incorrect. Try, in the parent folder of .git, where you see src: `git check-ignore -v -- src/consoleapplication1.cpp` (or `src/path/to/consoleapplication1.cpp`: I do not know where `consoleapplication1.cpp` is, under `src`)

Comment: The file is right in src and I'm doing it from the parent directory of src, and I typed in the path as you said ('src/filename'), but i still get the 'unknown option' error.  If I put in a space like so '- v -- src/filename' it instead returns no information at all, and just goes to the new input line.

Comment: @nof there is no space between - and v: it is -v, not - v.

Comment: I didn't have a space in -v.  Must have been an typo in the comment

Comment: @nofreewill " I do not know where `consoleapplication1.cpp` is, under `src/`": the idea of `git check-ignore` is to check if a given file is ignored: you need to know the exact path of that file under `src/`.

Comment: I said the file is right under src.  If you don't want to help, fine, I'll learn some other way.

Comment: @nofreewill Strange then. Not sure why the "unknown option" comes from. What version of Git for windows are you using?

Comment: 2.35.1.windows.1

Comment: @nofreewill Just in case, can you do a `git update-git-for-windows`? (to switch to `2.35.1.windows.2`)

Comment: Alright, I updated to windows.2 (checked version to make sure).  Now I type in git check-ignore -v -- src/ConsoleApplication1.cpp  and nothing happens still

Comment: error: pathspec 'consoleapplication1.cpp' did not match any file(s) known to git  ------
I cd into src as well

Comment: @nofreewill Is it possible the file was renamed from `consoleapplication1.cpp` to `ConsoleApplication1.cpp` (same letters, different case: upper/lowercase)?

Comment: No, it was already like that.